# Nvidia GTX 1650 not detected in Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I recently bought this machine: [ASUS TUF FX505DT - AMD Ryzen 5 3550H with GTX 1650 4GB](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-FX505DD-DT-DU/specifications/). It came with Windows 10 preinstaleld. The GTX 1650 graphics card worked in Windows without any issue. After I cleaned my SSD, disabled Secure Boot in BIOS and installed Ubuntu 18.04.3, the graphics card is not recognized.

I added `graphics-drivers/ppa`, purged all existing NVIDIA packages, installed `nvidia-driver-430` (tried 435 as well), but still it didn't work. I've also installed `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` using the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

This what Additional Drivers shows before installing the drivers:

[image: additional driver before install]

This what Additional Drivers shows after installing the drivers:

[image: additional driver after install]

This is the *About* info regarding the machine:

[image: about the machine]

Product model is showing as *Unknown* in the Additional Drivers settings.
Product model is just NVIDIA in `lshw -C display`.

```
shivakumaar@techpack-tuf:~$ sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for shivakumaar: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:67 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:f000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Picasso
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: c2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:65 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f7500000-f757ffff
shivakumaar@techpack-tuf:~$ sudo nvidia-xconfig

WARNING: Unable to locate/open X configuration file.

Package xorg-server was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xorg-server.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'xorg-server' found
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'

shivakumaar@techpack-tuf:~$ nvidia-detector
none
shivakumaar@techpack-tuf:~$ nvidia-settings

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:2313): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 13:01:50.443: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 13:01:50.448: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 13:01:50.448: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

[image: nvida x controller settings]

```
shivakumaar@techpack-tuf:~$ nvidia-smi
Sat Sep 28 13:02:14 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 435.21       Driver Version: 435.21       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1650    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   42C    P8     2W /  N/A |      0MiB /  3911MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

shivakumaar@techpack-tuf:~$ nvidia-debugdump --list
Found 1 NVIDIA devices
    Device ID:              0
    Device name:            GeForce GTX 1650
    GPU internal ID:        GPU-ba92a04a-ae32-bc09-62df-9fe847ba81ca
```

After installing the drivers, if I reboot and try to login into Ubuntu (Xorg), it freezes in the login screen or logs out immediately. But Ubuntu (Wayland) login works fine. But even with all the drivers installed, the screen flickers constantly in Wayland.

Comment: The command to add `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` has a `-r` flag. This flag is used to remove a ppa. I suppose it's a typo.

Comment: After installing the drivers, are you sure that Ubuntu is using Nvidia or not? 
If not, then try to select it using `sudo prime-select nvidia`

Comment: @user3140225, yes its a typo indeed. Thank you for pointing it out. I've corrected it.

Comment: @singrium After installing the drivers, I am sure Ubuntu was not using Nvidia. _About_ section as well as the output of `glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"` showed AMD only.

Comment: I've got the GTX 1650 working by adding `Option "PrimaryGPU" "Yes"` to the OutputClass of /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf as per here https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1051984/linux/amd-ryzen-5-mobile-nvidia-gtx-1050-login-loop-ubuntu-18-04/post/5340819/#5340819

```

Comment: i know your post is a few months old but someone recently got the nvidia gpu working correctly in linux manjaro on the FX505DT which i am currently trying to do myself but heres the guide. https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/f79trt/how_to_setup_a_ryzen_laptop_with_an_nvidia_gpu/

Comment: I have the same machine and having the same issue. I want to use `prime-select` though.

Comment: UPDATE: I recently installed 20.04 LTS and it works by default without any issue. I still have screen flickering, usual after unlocking the screen lock. I run this command `xset dpms force off` repeatedly until the flickering stops. Other than that its working fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the poster's comment to a detailed fix;

Do not add graphics drivers ppa and if you did it, remove everything including the ppa.

Open up the ***Additional Drivers*** from menu and select the proprietary tested driver and reboot.

Then create the directory and copy the file in it by following commands:

```
    sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
    sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

Then add `Option "PrimaryGPU" "Yes"` to the `OutputClass` of the following file

```
sudo vim /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf
```

It should look like this in the end:

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Option "PrimaryGPU" "Yes"    
    Identifier "nvidia"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection
```

Then reboot. After rebooting, try `nvidia-smi` command to see if it works.

I got gtx1660ti working with this soluiton well.

Comment: woooow!!! thanks!!! a thousands thanks, it works!!! This answer should be rated as +10000 hehe thank you again!!! BTW the same happens with Ubuntu 20 on this Laptop: HP Pavilion Gaming 15-EC-1011NS AMD Ryzen 5 4600H/8GB/512GB SSD/GTX 1650/15.6"

Comment: Glad it helped. I did follow the links in the comments and thought I would write what I did as an answer. Unfortunately I always had trouble with the open source drivers in the past and I never suggest it to people having trouble.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work on Ubuntu 20.04 with AMD® Ryzen 7 4800h with radeon graphics × 16.

Comment: @Displee go to the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` and remove any file non-related with nvidia

Comment: Tried a million things and this is the only thing that worked. Thanks a ton!