# Ubuntu only detects 6 GB out of 8GB RAM

Tags: drivers, ram, gpu

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and my laptop has 8 GB ram but I'm only able to 6gm of it in ubuntu. Also, I'm not able to get a proper driver for my Nvidia GTX 1650. What shall I do?

[image: These are my system details.]

Comment: @Nmath Most likely OP wanted to say that Ubuntu only detects 6 GB RAM out of 8 GB. Let's delete these comments

Comment: Possibly related, but may not be a duplicate - https://askubuntu.com/q/1092593/124466

Comment: Check this out for NVidia https://askubuntu.com/q/1177248/124466