While installing Ubuntu on a separate SSD the second SSD and HDD are not showing and it's only showing the Windows boot SSD
I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 11 on a separate SSD, but during the installation my secondary SSD is not showing. It's only showing my main Windows boot SSD and Ubuntu boot USB thumb drive, and it's not showing the other storage drives.

What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Is this an NVME SSD? If so, https://askubuntu.com/a/1032188/380067. Off the top of my head, I don't remember if the "missing AHCI driver on Windows" warning still is still relevant in case of Windows 11, and, most importantly, I don't remember if switching SATA mode messes with the TPM enough to trigger the invalidation of BitLocker keys stored in the TPM.

I would 1. Make sure the drive hosting the Windows installation is not BitLocker-encrypted 2. Boot Windows into safe mode 3. Switch SATA mode from RAID to AHCI 4. Attempt to install Ubuntu again. If the drive hosting the Windows installation is BitLocker-encrypted, wait for someone to confirm that it's safe to switch SATA mode with BitLocker keys stored in the TPM.

@kos If you got the 4 list items in the previous comment from another answer at Ask Ubuntu please provide a link to it, or else please post your comment as an answer to this question, then comment to me here so that I will be informed that I can upvote it.

@karel No I came up with it, but I was seeking confirmation for the TPM / BitLocker part cause I'm not sure about that one. The TPM is so sensitive about everything that I might have just made that part up.

@kos You could post the non-TPM part as an answer and post the part about TPM as a comment about your own answer pending confirmation.

@karel Then it'd be mostly the same as this one: https://askubuntu.com/a/1032188/380067. Honestly I can't find much about what I'm worried about, so perhaps I just made that up. But I wouldn't wanna suggest something potentially dangerous (nor have people wasting time recovering the encryption key "just for safety" if it isn't necessary). I'll try and figure this out, I'd like to understand this for myself as well

This question is similar to: Installing Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS but it's not detecting my Samsung PCIe NVME SSD. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
