# Accidentally installed Ubuntu to my Intel Optane Memory (MEMPEK1J016GA)

Tags: boot, 18.04, partitioning, hard-drive

I was attempting to install **Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS** for the very first time without help from a tutorial and I managed to somehow install Ubuntu on my intel optane memory instead of my hard drive.

When I look at the disks, **my hard drive "Acer" comes up as a removable drive** - when it is a hard drive installed into the laptop.

I am wondering if it is possible to **change my file-system location to my internal hard drive** as my optane memory is only a small capacity.

Comment: You filesystem can span multiple drives. The Optane is a good place for your core system. The old OS or data was wiped when you erroneously committed your changes and installed Ubuntu there.

Comment: How would I mount my home directory and where the software gets installed to another drive? Also it sometimes takes a few seconds to detect the HDD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intel Optane Memory support for Ubuntu and Windows 10 dual boot on Dell i7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009710/intel-optane-memory-support-for-ubuntu-and-windows-10-dual-boot-on-dell-i7)  Optane is not Linux-compatible. The Ubuntu installation tutorial is at  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0